# Wrong shapes for given matrices in OPENCV

Tags: opencv

I am trying to perform facial recogntion using opencv. For this the training and test images have to be of the same size. 
 So I used this function:

```
resize(testing,output, images[0].size(),0,0,INTER_NEAREST);
```

Where testing is my Mat from the webcam , Output is the resized image , images[0].size() is my database of vector images. 
 However I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Wrong shapes for given matrices. Was size(src) = (1,921600), 
size(W) = (307200,6).) in subspaceProject,
file /home/someplae/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/contrib/src/lda.cpp, 
line 187
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/someplace/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/contrib/src/lda.cpp:187: 
error: (-5) Wrong shapes for given matrices. Was size(src) = (1,921600), size(W) = (307200,6). 
in function subspaceProject
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although you don't provide enough code to verify, I can infer the problem from the given number of elements. Your test matrix is `921600 = 3 * 307200`... So I guess your input matrix is not a grayscale matrix, but still is in BGR representation.

You should use [cv::cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#void%20cvtColor%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20code,%20int%20dstCn%29) to convert the matrix to grayscale, before resizing it:

- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html