# OpenCV FaceRecognizer wrong shapes for given matrices

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to make a FisherFaceRecognizer's predict() method work, but I keep getting an error

> Bad argument (Wrong shapes for given matrices. Was size(src) =
>   (1,108000), size(W) = (36000,1).) in subspaceProject, file
>   /tmp/opencv-DCb7/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/contrib/src/lda.cpp, line 187

This is similar to a question that was asked at [Wrong shapes for given matrices in OPENCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032658/wrong-shapes-for-given-matrices-in-opencv)
but in my case, both source and training images are the same data type, full color.

My code is adapted from the tutorial at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#fisherfaces

however, my test image is larger than the training images, so I needed to work on a region of interest (ROI) of the right size.

Here's how I read the images and converted sizes.  I cloned the ROI matrix because an
earlier error message told me the target matrix must be contiguous:

```
vector<Mat> images;
images.push_back( cvLoadImage( trainingList[i].c_str()));
```

---

```
IplImage* img;
img = cvLoadImage( imgName.c_str() );
```

---

```
// take ROI and clone into a new Mat
Mat testSample1(img, Rect( xLoc, yLoc, images[0].cols, images[0].rows));
Mat testSample = testSample1.clone();
```

---

```
// Create a FisherFaceRecognizer in OpenCV
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> FFR = createFisherFaceRecognizer(0,DBL_MAX);
model->train(images, labels);

cout << " check of data type testSample is " << testSample.type() << " images is " << images[0].type() << endl;

int predictedLabel = model->predict(testSample);
//
```

I get an exception message at the predict statement.

The cout statement tells me both matrices have type 16, yet somehow it still doesn't believe the matrices are the same size and data type...

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure the shapes, not types 
Try

```
cout << testSample.rows << testSample.cols << images[0].rows << images[0].cols ;
```

Also 
ensure that both ,training img & test img, are in the same color space
If not, Try

```
cvtColor(testSample, testSample_inSameSpaceOfTraining, CV_BGR2***); // default opencv colors "BGR"
```

Comment: I found out that I needed to specify grayscale for both training and test images, like this:

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the FisherFaceRecognizer requires grayscale images, so I should have loaded both training and test images like this:

```
 trainingImages.push_back( imread( trainingList[i].c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));
```

and

```
  Mat img;    
  img = imread( imgName.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
```

(also reconciled the type of img for consistency).  The grayscale-only requirement is documented in the OpenCV reference manual (pdf available online) but apparently not in any of the online tutorials or other documents for FisherFaceRecognizer.